# Removing a Web Front-End server from Farm (Load Balancing)

Tags: server-farm, load-balancing

I am currently working on a project where we have developed a portal on SharePoint. Currently we have two servers which is using Load Balancing. We're experiencing a lot of difficulties connected to this, so we are thinking about removing one of the Web Front-End servers from the farm.

Could this cause any kind of problems that you can think of? I want to be sure before I recommend to this to our client. Anything you could think of would be great. Also pro's you can think of by doing this is appreciated.

The load balancing was agreed on from the beginning of the project, before we came in as consultants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What kind of issues are you experiencing? If a NLB is in place, you can still hit an individual server and load the SP site bypassing the NLB (you'll need to make sure the site has alternate access mapping set for the server name).

But if you want to remove it, it should be straight forward, hop onto that box and uninstall SharePoint, it'll take it out of the farm cleanly. First, go to Central Admin Services on Farm and ensure there are no unique services running on the server.

After install, you may want to remove the NLB as well? It'll know a box is missing (that's what they do ;)) but why keep the complexity in there. And then this brings me to my first point, you can access a web server directly....

HTH

Comment: This is the method we're going for. Still want the possibility to add a server at a later point, if we see that it's necessary.

Comment: You can always add another server later on. Let us know how it goes!

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem removing a WFE if you can handle the load with a single server. The only thing you are sacrificing is resilience since if that single server fails you will be offline.